# HikariCP(2.4.6) in Tomcat(8.0.32) lib directory doesn't log

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, tomcat8, hikaricp

While logging works nicely when the `hikari`(2.4.6) jar is bundled in the application's war, when we move it to Tomcat(8.0.32) `/lib` directory, `hikari` stops logging. I have followed a similar issue in hikaricp github [(809)](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/809) where there was some guidance in achieving this, but I cannot get it to work. For our application it is very crucial to monitor the pool:

`2017-02-01 12:27:17.274 DEBUG 26240 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)`

so we need a way to get this info in `catalina.out`

My tomcat setup is as following:

`/lib` directory:

[image]

and my `logging.properties`:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINEST
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = manager.

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = host-manager.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter




############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

# For example, set the org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase logger to log
# each component that extends LifecycleBase changing state:
#org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.level = FINE

# To see debug messages in TldLocationsCache, uncomment the following line:
#org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache.level = FINE

com.zaxxer.hikari.level = FINEST
com.zaxxer.hikari.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler
```

Please provide me some info on how to get this working.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

First of all, tomcat server internal logging must be changed from [Apache Commons Logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging) to [log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j). The procedure to do this is described [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j). 
Assuming having read the links above and downloaded the aforementioned jars from the `extras` bundle (`tomcat-juli-adapters.jar`, `tomcat-juli.jar`)

- `log4j.properties` file should be placed to `tomcat/lib` directory.
- Delete or rename `logging.properties` file from `tomcat/conf` directory, so `tomcat` doesn't pick it up during startup.
- Copy the following jars to `tomcat/lib` directory: `log4j-1.2.17.jar`, `tomcat-juli-adapters.jar`
- Copy and replace the following jar to `tomcat/bin` directory: `tomcat-juli.jar`

After the above steps, `tomcat` should now log using `log4j`.

To enable `HikariCP` logging do the following:

- Edit `log4j.properties` file and at the end add the following line: 
  `log4j.logger.com.zaxxer.hikari = DEBUG`
- Make sure the following jars exist in `tomcat/lib` directory:

  - HikariCP-2.4.6.jar
  - jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar
  - slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar
  - slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar
  - jul-to-slf4j-1.7.21.jar

My `log4j.properties` file:

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, CATALINA

# Define all the appenders
log4j.appender.CATALINA = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.CATALINA.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/catalina
log4j.appender.CATALINA.Append = true
log4j.appender.CATALINA.Encoding = UTF-8
# Roll-over the log once per day
log4j.appender.CATALINA.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.appender.LOCALHOST = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/localhost
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.Append = true
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.Encoding = UTF-8
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.appender.MANAGER = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MANAGER.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/manager
log4j.appender.MANAGER.Append = true
log4j.appender.MANAGER.Encoding = UTF-8
log4j.appender.MANAGER.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.MANAGER.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MANAGER.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/host-manager
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.Append = true
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.Encoding = UTF-8
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.appender.CONSOLE = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Encoding = UTF-8
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

# Configure which loggers log to which appenders
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost] = INFO, LOCALHOST
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager] =\
  INFO, MANAGER
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager] =\
  INFO, HOST-MANAGER

log4j.logger.com.zaxxer.hikari = DEBUG
```